# How to display CImg image in CWnd

Tags: mfc, cimg

CImg library contains CImgDisplay to display CImg images. How can I load an image using CImg and display in a CWnd derived class in my MFC application?

Comment: You have to translate it into CImage/CBitmap object and render inside your CWnd.